# Prove that $ f(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{4} e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x-\theta|}$ is not an exponential family.

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I want to prove that $ f(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{4} e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x-\theta|}$ does not belong to the exponential family.

By definition, it is easy to answer such questions as 'prove a given distribution fuction is in the exponential family', but I fail to copy with this question to prove "does not belong to the exponential family". Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What's an exponential family?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family

Comment: $f$ belongs to the exponential family if $f(x \mid \theta) = h(x) e^{\eta(\theta) T(x) + A(\theta)}$ for some functions $h, A, \eta$ and $T.$ Indeed this is hard, and I don't see an obvious way to do it. I suppose it will have to do with the fact that $f$ is maximised on the line $x = \theta$